How do muslims deal with verses in the gospels stating Jesus came to save the world?
My understanding from reading the Quran is that the Torah and gospels are considered to be scripture.  How do muslims handle the verses in the gospels that state Jesus came to save the world?  That seems counter to what the Quran says that Jesus is just a prophet.
Here is a good collection of what the gospels say about Jesus' mission.
John 1:12 ESV
But to all who did receive him, who believed in his name, he gave the right to become children of God,
John 1:29 ESV
The next day he saw Jesus coming toward him, and said, “Behold, the Lamb of God, who takes away the sin of the world!
John 3:14-17 ESV
Just as Moses lifted up the snake in the wilderness, so the Son of Man must be lifted up, that everyone who believes may have eternal life in him.
For God so loved the world, that he gave his only Son, that whoever believes in him should not perish but have eternal life. For God did not send his Son into the world to condemn the world, but in order that the world might be saved through him.
John 3:36 ESV
Whoever believes in the Son has eternal life; whoever does not obey the Son shall not see life, but the wrath of God remains on him.
John 5:24 ESV
Truly, truly, I say to you, whoever hears my word and believes him who sent me has eternal life. He does not come into judgment, but has passed from death to life.
John 8:51 ESV
Truly, truly, I say to you, if anyone keeps my word, he will never see death.
John 10:11 NIV
I am the good shepherd. The good shepherd lays down his life for the sheep.
John 10:17-18 ESV
For this reason the Father loves me, because I lay down my life that I may take it up again. No one takes it from me, but I lay it down of my own accord. I have authority to lay it down, and I have authority to take it up again. This charge I have received from my Father.
John 12:46-48
I have come into the world as light, so that whoever believes in me may not remain in darkness. If anyone hears my words and does not keep them, I do not judge him; for I did not come to judge the world but to save the world. The one who rejects me and does not receive my words has a judge; the word that I have spoken will judge him on the last day.
John 14:6 ESV
Jesus said to him, “I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me.
John 15:13 ESV
Greater love has no one than this, that someone lay down his life for his friends.
Matthew 1:21 ESV
She will bear a son, and you shall call his name Jesus, for he will save his people from their sins.
Matthew 20:28 ESV
Even as the Son of Man came not to be served but to serve, and to give his life as a ransom for many.
Matthew 26:2 NIV
“As you know, the Passover is two days away—and the Son of Man will be handed over to be crucified.”
Matthew 26:12 NIV
"When she poured this perfume on my body, she did it to prepare me for burial."
Matthew 26:27-28 NIV
Then he took a cup, and when he had given thanks, he gave it to them, saying, “Drink from it, all of you. This is my blood of the covenant, which is poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins."
Matthew 26:31-32 NIV
Then Jesus told them, “This very night you will all fall away on account of me, for it is written:
“‘I will strike the shepherd,
and the sheep of the flock will be scattered.'
But after I have risen, I will go ahead of you into Galilee.”
Mark 10:45 ESV
For even the Son of Man came not to be served but to serve, and to give his life as a ransom for many.
Mark 16:16 ESV
Whoever believes and is baptized will be saved, but whoever does not believe will be condemned.
Luke 9:22 ESV
Saying, “The Son of Man must suffer many things and be rejected by the elders and chief priests and scribes, and be killed, and on the third day be raised.”
Luke 24:46-47 NIV
He told them, “This is what is written: The Messiah will suffer and rise from the dead on the third day, and repentance for the forgiveness of sins will be preached in his name to all nations, beginning at Jerusalem."

Well, the short answer is that mainstream Islam considers the Qur'an to be without error and a confirmation of the original message sent in the previous scriptures, but not necessarily any particular translation or edition that has survived to the current day, so any obvious contradictions between the Bible and the Qur'an is merely a result of corruption in the Bible and there would be nothing to reconcile.
That said, the rest of this answer presumes that the verses which state Jesus came to "save the world" are valid, and attempt to reconcile them with Islamic teachings. You don't quote any particular Biblical verses, but I'll include the following excerpt from John which I think encapsulates what you're saying:

47  “If anyone hears my words but does not keep them, I do not judge that person. For I did not come to judge the world, but to save the world.
48 There is a judge for the one who rejects me and does not accept my words; the very words I have spoken will condemn them at the last day.
49 For I did not speak on my own, but the Father who sent me commanded me to say all that I have spoken.
50 I know that his command leads to eternal life. So whatever I say is just what the Father has told me to say.”
— John 12:47-50

These verses are a pretty good summary of the role of a prophet, as they're seen in Islam: One sent not to judge others by one's own conviction, but to convey the words of Allah, Al-Hakam, The Ultimate Judge. One sent, not to condemn a people, but to warn them against a punishment that is inevitable if they do not repent or change their ways.
Or to save them, as it were.

72 They have certainly disbelieved who say, " Allah is the Messiah, the son of Mary" while the Messiah has said, "O Children of Israel, worship Allah , my Lord and your Lord." Indeed, he who associates others with Allah - Allah has forbidden him Paradise, and his refuge is the Fire. And there are not for the wrongdoers any helpers.
73 They have certainly disbelieved who say, " Allah is the third of three." And there is no god except one God. And if they do not desist from what they are saying, there will surely afflict the disbelievers among them a painful punishment.
74 So will they not repent to Allah and seek His forgiveness? And Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.
75 The Messiah, son of Mary, was not but a messenger; [other] messengers have passed on before him. And his mother was a supporter of truth. They both used to eat food. Look how We make clear to them the signs; then look how they are deluded.
— Surah Al-Ma'idah 72-75

The Qur'an makes clear that the Messiah was "not but a messenger" to directly counter the Christian claims that he was God in the flesh. It is not meant to imply that he didn't also have a significant role to play.
Moses was a messenger but he was also responsible for freeing the children of Israel from Pharoah and leading them to the promised land. David was a messenger but he was also the chosen king of the Kingdom of Israel. These functions they performed not in spite of being a messenger from God, but because of it for it is what God willed of them.
Similarly, Jesus had his own role to fulfill in his duty as a prophet: Even the Qur'an explicitly refers to him as "Messiah". So even if the biblical claim that he came to "save the world" means more than just warning people against the consequences of disbelief, it does not diminish his role as a prophet and a messenger in any way, and Islamically there's no reason to reject it.
However, even if this were the case, the Qur'an and Islamic teachings do not provide any further explanation as to how Jesus was meant to "save the world" so we would be speculating based on the same original source material, being his own claims in the Bible itself. What we do know to be wrong is the Christian belief that Jesus needs to be God in the flesh in order to fulfill this role, or that God needs to be one of three in order to fulfill this role: These are the claims that the Qur'an rejects in no uncertain terms.

As the question was updated with more verses after I posted this, an addendum:
First of all, there's way too many verses listed for me to even attempt to reconcile them all individually and maintain a coherent answer of reasonable length, so I won't attempt to do so. Ultimately, I don't believe it would've affected the meat of my answer anyway.
Secondly, attempting to explain the will and rationale of the Almighty based only on a selection of cherry-picked verses is an insult to the Almighty, and I refuse to play that game. In order to properly understand and explain the Bible, one needs to consider the Bible in its entirety, which is completely out of scope here.
However, I will elaborate a bit more, based more on the common Christian interpretation of the above verses than the literal words used.
First of all, the concept of intercession is valid in Islam, that being the idea that Allah has given authority to others to save them from Hell:

85 On the Day We will gather the righteous to the Most Merciful as a delegation
86 And will drive the criminals to Hell in thirst
87 None will have intercession except he who had taken from the Most Merciful a covenant.
— Surat Maryam 85-87

So the concept of Christ Jesus being given this authority — that his followers can be saved through him, despite their own sins — is not unacceptable in Islam, although I don't know of any authentic Islamic references proving that this is the case.
What is strange, however, is the idea that Christ Jesus' intercession is somehow required for forgiveness, as this implies that Allah lacks the power or the ability to forgive Himself, despite being the Most Merciful, the Most Forgiving. The Qur'an is clear that this is not the case, that He has the power to forgive whosoever He wills:

14 And to Allah belongs the dominion of the heavens and the earth. He forgives whom He wills and punishes whom He wills. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful.
— Surat Al-Fath 14

The idea that Christ Jesus' sacrifice was somehow necessary to achieve salvation definitely goes against this, and in my personal opinion it only makes sense in the context of the previous covenants; Allah is not limited in His forgiveness, but Allah is also Most Just and if He has made a promise, the idea that He would break that promise, or that he would lie, goes against His very nature.
And this is why I mention above that explaining any verse of the Bible requires understanding the Bible in its entirety; it is a sin to believe in only part of the Scripture and ignore the rest. However, I would point to the section of Blessings and Curses in Deuteronomy 28, which is too long to quote here,  but tl;dr it's a promise of punishment made by the Almighty for the children of Israel if they ever break His Covenant. Not just a vague warning, this is a clear PROMISE, and Allah's promise is true.
I would also like to point out the following verse from Leviticus 17:

11 For the life of a creature is in the blood, and I have given it to you to make atonement for yourselves on the altar; it is the blood that makes atonement for one’s life.
— Leviticus 17:11

"And I have given it to you…" being the important part here; this was a privilege that was granted specifically to the children of Israel that blood can be used as atonement, as reparation for wrongdoing, as forgiveness for sins.
Between these, the concept of Christ Jesus's sacrifice being an element needed to forgive breach of the Covenant, within the terms of the Covenant can be understood. However, for anyone else, it would've been absolutely unnecessary because we were never bound by the Covenant in the first place. Allah can forgive us or punish us as He wishes without ever going against His own word.
Just to be clear, the above is my own personal speculation, and this is all rather tangential to the scope of the site. I am hardly a biblical scholar and I'm sure Christian scholars have their own explanations for all of the above, nor does it necessarily coincide with mainstream Islamic teachings which consider the Bible to be mostly irrelevant due to abrogation or corruption: Muslims know the Qur'an to be true, and the responsibility of understanding the previous scriptures was on the nations those scriptures were revealed to.

Interesting!  Sorry, I should have included verses.  The gospels say more than just a generic "save the world".  I'll add the verses as I'd be interested in your take on them.

@yters I have expanded on my answer, but this is veering very much into scope creep and off-topic territory.

Muslims believe the Injeel to be a divine scripture. But they do not necessarily believe that the books that the Christians have selected and transmitted are faithful reproductions of that scripture. Rather they believe that these scriptures have been corrupted with additions, omissions and/or misinterpretations.

وإن منهم لفريقا يلوون ألسنتهم بالكتاب لتحسبوه من الكتاب وما هو من الكتاب ويقولون هو من عند الله وما هو من عند الله ويقولون على الله الكذب وهم يعلمون
And indeed, there is among them a party who alter the Scripture with their tongues so you may think it is from the Scripture, but it is not from the Scripture. And they say, "This is from Allah," but it is not from Allah. And they speak untruth about Allah while they know.
— Quran 3:78

What is the Injeel according to Islam? It is a revelation from Allah to Jesus:

وقفينا على آثارهم بعيسى ابن مريم مصدقا لما بين يديه من التوراة وآتيناه الإنجيل فيه هدى ونور ومصدقا لما بين يديه من التوراة وهدى وموعظة للمتقين
And We sent, following in their footsteps, Jesus, the son of Mary, confirming that which came before him in the Torah; and We gave him the Gospel, in which was guidance and light and confirming that which preceded it of the Torah as guidance and instruction for the righteous.
— Quran 5:46

What are the four Gospels according to Christians themselves? They are books containing Jesus's biography, composed by his disciples under divine inspiration, and transmitted to us through Christians (who are not trustworthy near the Muslims). These Gospels might 'contain' teachings from the Injeel, but they are not equal to the Injeel.  There is a difference between believing in the Injeel and believing in a specific verse in the current Gospel of Luke. It is similar to how a Christian believing in the Gospel does not mean that he accepts some verse in the Gospel of Thomas or the Gospel of Barnabas. And it is similar to how a Muslim believing in ahadith does not necessarily mean that they believe in every weak or fabricated hadith or that they accept some specific interpretation derived from a particular hadith.
Muslims consider the Christian Gospels to be unreliable sources. If some verses from them seem to be in apparent contradiction to Islamic beliefs then Muslims simply say that it is possible that the verses are being misinterpreted and it is also possible that their wording of those has been tampered with.
The stance of the Muslims towards the Christian gospels is indicated in the following reports:

كان أهل الكتاب يقرءون التوراة بالعبرانية ويفسرونها بالعربية لأهل الإسلام فقال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم  لا تصدقوا أهل الكتاب، ولا تكذبوهم وقولوا آمنا بالله وما أنزل إلينا وما أنزل إليكم
The people of the Book used to read the Torah in Hebrew and then explain it in Arabic to the Muslims. Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said (to the Muslims). "Do not believe the people of the Book, nor disbelieve them, but say, 'We believe in Allah and whatever is revealed to us, and whatever is revealed to you.' "
— Bukhari


عن ابن عباس ـ رضى الله عنهما ـ قال يا معشر المسلمين، كيف تسألون أهل الكتاب، وكتابكم الذي أنزل على نبيه صلى الله عليه وسلم أحدث الأخبار بالله، تقرءونه لم يشب، وقد حدثكم الله أن أهل الكتاب بدلوا ما كتب الله وغيروا بأيديهم الكتاب، فقالوا هو من عند الله، ليشتروا به ثمنا قليلا
Ibn Abbas said, "O Muslims? How do you ask the people of the Scriptures, though your Book (i.e. the Qur'an) which was revealed to His Prophet is the most recent information from Allah and you recite it, the Book that has not been distorted? Allah has revealed to you that the people of the scriptures have changed with their own hands what was revealed to them and they have said (as regards their changed Scriptures): This is from Allah, in order to get some worldly benefit thereby."
— Bukhari


أن عمر بن الخطاب، أتى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم بكتاب أصابه من بعض أهل الكتب  ، فقرأه على النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فغضب وقال : ...  لا تسألوهم عن شيء فيخبروكم بحق فتكذبوا به، أو بباطل فتصدقوا به، والذي نفسي بيده لو أن موسى كان حيا، ما وسعه إلا أن يتبعني
Umar ibn al-Khattab came to the Prophet ﷺ with a book from the People of the Scripture and recited it, on which the Prophet got angry and said: ...
Do not ask the People of the Scripture about anything, lest they inform you of something which is true and you deny it, or something false and you accept it, by Allah if Moses was alive today it would not be lawful for him to do anything except to follow me
— Musnad Ahmad classed as authentic by al-Albani in Irwa' al-Ghaleel due to corroborating reports 


أن ناسا من المسلمين أتوا نبي الله صلى الله عليه وسلم بكتب، قد كتبوا فيها بعض ما يقول اليهود، فلما أن نظر فيها ألقاها، ثم قال: " كفى بها حماقة قوم -أو ضلالة قوم- أن يرغبوا عما جاءهم به نبيهم، إلى ما جاء به غير نبيهم، إلى قوم غيرهم "، فنـزلت: ( أولم يكفهم أنا أنـزلنا عليك الكتاب يتلى عليهم إن في ذلك لرحمة وذكرى لقوم يؤمنون )
Some Muslims brought some books on which the sayings of the Jews were written. The Prophet ﷺ threw them away and said: It is foolishness and misguidance for a people to turn away from what their Prophet brought them and to incline towards what another Prophet brought to another people. Then the following verse was revealed:

And is it not sufficient for them that We revealed to you the Book which is recited to them? Indeed in that is a mercy and reminder for a people who believe.
— Quran 29:51

— Tafsir al-Tabary

Muslims do not take their religious beliefs and laws from the Christian Gospels, nor do they study them for this purpose. Hence Muslims also do not have any canonical stance on the interpretation of individual verses from the gospels.
I am not going to respond to each individual verse you have quoted, but I will give cover general beliefs which are relevant. The Muslims believe that:

Jesus was a Messenger of Allah and the Messiah, sent to the Bani Israel. He was sent to give them guidance and law and to prophecy the advent of Muhammad ﵌. The beliefs he taught were the same as those of all previous Messengers and the same as the beliefs taught in Islam by Muhammad  ﵌, not something new or different.

شرع لكم من الدين ما وصى به نوحا والذي أوحينا إليك وما وصينا به إبراهيم وموسى وعيسى أن أقيموا الدين ولا تتفرقوا فيه
He has ordained for you of religion what He enjoined upon Noah and that which We have revealed to you, [O Muhammad], and what We enjoined upon Abraham and Moses and Jesus - to establish the religion and not be divided therein.
— Quran 42:13


أنا أولى الناس بعيسى ابن مريم في الدنيا والآخرة، والأنبياء إخوة لعلات، أمهاتهم شتى، ودينهم واحد
Both in this world and in the Hereafter, I am the nearest of all the people to Jesus, the son of Mary. The prophets are like paternal brothers; their mothers (laws) are different, but their religion is one.
— Bukhari


It is essential to believe in Jesus as being sent by Allah and to believe in the truthfulness of whatever he said (when authentically proven to be said by him, the authentic sources now being the Quran and Sunnah).  Anyone who disbelieves in him shall be in hell-fire for eternity. However the same applies to all other Messengers: anyone who disbelieves in Moses or Abraham or Noah will also be in eternal hell-fire.

إن الذين يكفرون بالله ورسله ويريدون أن يفرقوا بين الله ورسله ويقولون نؤمن ببعض ونكفر ببعض ويريدون أن يتخذوا بين ذلك سبيلا أولئك هم الكافرون حقًّا وأعتدنا للكافرين عذابًا مهينًا
Indeed, those who disbelieve in Allah and His messengers and wish to discriminate between Allah and His messengers and say, "We believe in some and disbelieve in others," and wish to adopt a way in between  -
Those are the disbelievers, truly. And We have prepared for the disbelievers a humiliating punishment.
— Quran 4:150-151


Jesus has a high status near Allah and is loved by him, like all other Prophets and Messengers. In fact Jesus has a very high status even among the Prophets, because he is among the "Ulul 'Azm" - the Arch-Prophets. However Muhammad ﵌ has higher rank than him, and many Muslims hold the belief that Abraham and Moses also have a higher rank than him.

إذ قالت الملائكة يا مريم إن الله يبشرك بكلمة منه اسمه المسيح عيسى ابن مريم وجيها في الدنيا والآخرة ومن المقربين
[And mention] when the angels said, "O Mary, indeed Allah gives you good tidings of a word from Him, whose name will be the Messiah, Jesus, the son of Mary - distinguished in this world and the Hereafter and among those brought near [to Allah].
— Quran 3:45


Jesus was not the son of Allah and is not divine, rather he was a human and a servant of Allah. The exaggerated beliefs of the Christians about his divinity are false, in direct opposition of Jesus's teachings and amount to Kufr and Shirk which will lead the Christians into eternal damnation:

لقد كفر الذين قالوا إن الله هو المسيح ابن مريم وقال المسيح يا بني إسرائيل اعبدوا الله ربي وربكم إنه من يشرك بالله فقد حرم الله عليه الجنة ومأواه النار وما للظالمين من أنصار
They have certainly disbelieved who say, "Allah is the Messiah, the son of Mary" while the Messiah has said, "O Children of Israel, worship Allah, my Lord and your Lord." Indeed, he who associates others with Allah - Allah has forbidden him Paradise, and his refuge is the Fire. And there are not for the wrongdoers any helpers.
— Quran 5:72


إن كل من في السماوات والأرض إلا آتي الرحمن عبدا
There is no one in the heavens and earth but that he comes to the Most Merciful as a servant.
— Quran 19:93


In the afterlife, people do not carry the burden of the sins committed by another person - unless they are directly guilty such as if they endorsed or assisted in the commission of that sin.

ولا تكسب كل نفس إلا عليها ولا تزر وازرة وزر أخرى
And every soul earns not [blame] except against itself, and no bearer of burdens will bear the burden of another.
— Quran 6:164

This is something also present in the past scriptures:

أم لم ينبأ بما في صحف موسى وإبراهيم الذي وفى ألا تزر وازرة وزر أخرى
Or has he not been informed of what was in the scriptures of Moses And [of] Abraham, who fulfilled [his obligations] - That no bearer of burdens will bear the burden of another
— Quran 53:36-38


Allah is Forgiving and Merciful. Sins can be forgiven through sincere repentance.

ومن يعمل سوءا أو يظلم نفسه ثم يستغفر الله يجد الله غفورا رحيما
And whoever does a wrong or wrongs himself but then seeks forgiveness of Allah will find Allah Forgiving and Merciful.
— Quran 4:110


قل يا عبادي الذين أسرفوا على أنفسهم لا تقنطوا من رحمة الله إن الله يغفر الذنوب جميعا إنه هو الغفور الرحيم
Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful."
— Quran 39:53


Jesus was not crucified or killed. Rather he was saved by Allah from the plot of those who tried to kill him, and he was raised up to the heavens.

إذ قال الله يا عيسى ابن مريم اذكر نعمتي عليك ... وإذ كففت بني إسرائيل عنك إذ جئتهم بالبينات فقال الذين كفروا منهم إن هذا إلا سحر مبين
[The Day] when Allah will say, "O Jesus, Son of Mary, remember My favor upon you ... when I restrained the Children of Israel from [killing] you
— Quran 5:110


وما قتلوه وما صلبوه ...  وما قتلوه يقينا بل رفعه الله إليه وكان الله عزيزا حكيما
And they did not kill him, nor did they crucify him ...  And they did not kill him, for certain. Rather, Allah raised him to Himself. And ever is Allah Exalted in Might and Wise.
— Quran 4:157


Jesus will return in the end of times, he will defeat the anti-christ and spread Islam everywhere. Jesus saved and will save the people by guiding them, having them accept Islam and turning them away from disbelief and disobedience to God. That is how salvation is achieved.



According to Quran Jesus the Christ PBUH has not been killed on a cross, and according to other Islamic resources a companion of him was executed instead, as the Companions of Jesus the Christ PBUH asked for a Heavenly table spread with foods to be sent to them, and Allah sent to them what they asked for with only one condition, that if any one of them go astray after that miracle he will be punished with a penalty not inflicted on any one among all the peoples (فَمَنْ يَكْفُرْ بَعْدُ مِنْكُمْ فَإِنِّي أُعَذِّبُهُ عَذَابًا لَا أُعَذِّبُهُ أَحَدًا مِنَ الْعَالَمِينَ), and that penalty was to change his appearance, for him to look like Jesus the Christ PBUH, for Jews to take him wrong and kill him out of mistake, and that's why Saint Peter PBUH denied the fake Jesus as his master.

وَ قَوْلِهِمْ إِنَّا قَتَلْنَا الْمَسِيحَ عِيسَي ابْنَ مَرْيَمَ
رَسُولَ اللَّهِ وَ مَا قَتَلُوهُ وَ مَا صَلَبُوهُ وَ لَكِنْ شُبِّهَ
لَهُمْ وَ إِنَّ الَّذِينَ اخْتَلَفُوا فِيهِ لَفِي شَكٍّ مِنْهُ مَا
لَهُمْ بِهِ مِنْ عِلْمٍ إِلَّا اتِّبَاعَ الظَّنِّ وَ مَا قَتَلُوهُ
يَقِينًا. بَلْ رَفَعَهُ اللَّهُ إِلَيْهِ وَ كَانَ اللَّهُ عَزِيزًا حَكِيمًا
And [for] their saying, 'Indeed, we have killed the Messiah, Jesus,
the son of Mary, the messenger of Allah.' And they did not kill him,
nor did they crucify him; but [another] was made to resemble him to
them. And indeed, those who differ over it are in doubt about it.
They have no knowledge of it except the following of assumption. And they
did not kill him, for certain. Rather, Allah raised him to Himself. And ever is Allah Exalted in Might and Wise

So what happened to Jesus PBUH afterward? According to Quran cited above he was lifted to skies, and according to Ahadeeth right now he is alive in the second Heaven. Also according to at least Shia Ahadeeth that I am familiar with, he will return to the Earth, and he WILL save the world indeed together with Imam Mahdi PBUH for whom Muslims are all waiting. They both will fight against whom we call Dadjjal (دجال) and you call anti-Christ, and Satan will be killed at the end of the war. Some Ahadeeth narrates the story with so much details. After that Jesus PBUH will pray behind Imam Mahdi PBUH and the ruler-ship of Imam Mahdi PBUH begins. This will not be the end of history though, and Ahadeeth sometimes seem diverse in narrating two or three different scenarios for afterward until the Hereafter arises. So, maybe and only maybe, this is what you was looking forward about saving the world, something more than what the previous messengers were looking forward to do, or were expected/able to do.
PS. I have seen Western documentaries that advertise Imam Mahdi PBUH to be the anti-Christ. To us this is a try to promote Dadjjal as the real Chirst, and indeed Dadjjal will claim to be the God, and guess who can accept a man to be the God? Those who have been told all those stories added by Paul to the Christianity that Jesus was the God in a flesh, and all those incarnation stuffs. Interesting enough, Dadjjal will bring back to life a man of God (apparently the holy Kidhr PBUH) after he has been killed by Dadjjal, and Dadjjal will introduce it as the proof for him to be the God, again the same as what has been promoted over centuries by the main stream Christianity (it is not really the case that Dadjjal will bring him back to life, but it will appear to be so in the sight of regular people). Therefore Christians will largely be inclined to accept him as God, or Jesus the Christ, while he is indeed the very anti-Christ. Dadjjal has also other miracles, like his vehicle to travel is extremely fast, or that a mountain out of bread appears behind him when people are all hungry, and he has only one eye in his forehead. The war between Imam Mahdi PBUH and Christ PBUH on one side, and Dadjjal on the other side will not be so easy. That Westerners try to wash the evil's face and claim against the men of God is not limited to this case, but in those days an army of saint people will be returned to the Earth after maybe centuries passed from their death or martyrdom to help the true believers and guess what, Westerners have already spoiled the minds of people by concepts like zombies. Well, these are sometimes our understanding of the verses and Ahadeeth, and I cannot swear to God that what I have understood is the ultimate fact. so only a probable warning at this stage.
